# driver=self.driver AttributeError: 'loginpage' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, python-unittest

**demo1.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pandas as pd
import warnings
class Login(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUPClass(cls):
       cls.driver=webdriver.Firefox()

       cls.driver.maximize_window()
       cls.driver.get("http:***********")


#     @classmethod 
#     def tearDownClass(cls):
#      cls.driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main()
```

**demo2.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pandas as pd
import warnings
from demo import demo1 

class loginpage(demo1.Login):
    def test_login(self):
        driver=self.driver
        loginExcel = pd.read_excel(r"/root/eclipse-workspace/NMS/excel/login.xlsx")
        user = loginExcel["user"]
        pwd = loginExcel["pword"]


        i=0
        for i in range(2):
            username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')  
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(user.iloc[i])
            print("The username [" + user.iloc[i] + "] is entered")

            password= driver.find_element_by_name('password')
            driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(pwd.iloc[i])

            print("The Password [" + pwd.iloc[i] + "] is entered")
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)

            Login = driver.find_element_by_name('login').click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**demo3.py**
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import demo1
from demo2 import loginpage 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

## import demo2

```
import unittest

class configuration(demo1.Login):
    def test_demo(self):
        driver=self.driver

        test=loginpage().test_login()

        conf= driver.find_element_by_link_text('Configuration')
        hover=ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(conf)
        hover.perform()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/eclipse-workspace/NMS/src/demo/demo3.py", line 23, in test_demo
    test=loginpage().test_login()
  File "/root/eclipse-workspace/NMS/src/demo/demo2.py", line 21, in test_login
    driver=self.driver

## AttributeError: 'loginpage' object has no attribute 'driver'

### ERROR: test_login (demo2.loginpage)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/eclipse-workspace/NMS/src/demo/demo2.py", line 21, in test_login
    driver=self.driver

### AttributeError: 'loginpage' object has no attribute 'driver'

Ran 2 tests in 0.000s
FAILED (errors=2)**

Comment: In `driver=self.driver` where do you think that `self.driver` should come from? Should `driver` be inherited from parent class? Try just to remove `driver=self.driver`

Comment: global name 'driver' is not defined

Comment: Write method name correctly. `setUPClass` should be `setUpClass` to be found and executed on test class setup.